# Problema con un elemento con posicion Sticky y obtener el alto real con respecto a la pagina con JS

Tags: javascript, scroll, position, css-transform, sticky

Tengo un problema y es que tengo un div que tiene posicionamiento sticky y al intentar obtener el element.getBoundingClientRect().top con el que puedo obtener la posición real con respecto al alto total de la pagina me da un numero erróneo, ejemplo: altura de la pagina total [ 6300 ] - altura obtenida por el div con posicionamiento sticky [ 578.90 ].

No es correcto por que el elemento esta en la ultima sección de la pagina por que debería dar un numero parecido a 6300 o 6000 por ahí pero no pasa. Lamentablemente no puedo proporcionar el código completo por que la pagina esta hecho en WordPress pero si un ejemplo que tiene ese problema a menor escala, su finalidad es que cuando este moviéndose el elemento sticky otro elemento se modifique su transform - scale. Si se dan cuenta no importa en que posicion del scroll estemos se modifica el scale en el div dicho en vez que solo lo haga cuando el div sticky se mueva sea arriba o abajo y es por el problema dicho anteriormente. No se que podría ser el problema, ya estoy una semana con esto. :,(

Este es el codigo

```js
var stickyElement = document.querySelector(".sticky-element");
var contentElement = document.querySelector(".content");
var lastStickyElementPosition = stickyElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var minScale = 0.5; // Valor mínimo de escala
var smoothness = 0.0005; // Suavidad de la transición

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var currentStickyElementPosition = stickyElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  if (currentStickyElementPosition < lastStickyElementPosition) {
    // El elemento se está moviendo hacia abajo
    console.log("El elemento se mueve hacia abajo.");

    // Calcular la escala gradualmente con un valor mínimo
    var scale = Math.max(minScale, 1 - (currentStickyElementPosition * smoothness));
    contentElement.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
  } else if (currentStickyElementPosition > lastStickyElementPosition) {
    // El elemento se está moviendo hacia arriba
    console.log("El elemento se mueve hacia arriba.");

    // Calcular la escala gradualmente con un valor mínimo
    var scale = Math.max(minScale, 1 - (currentStickyElementPosition * smoothness));
    contentElement.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
  } else {
    // El elemento no se está moviendo verticalmente
    console.log("El elemento no se está moviendo verticalmente.");
  }

  lastStickyElementPosition = currentStickyElementPosition;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  height: 1000vh;
  /* Asegúrate de que haya suficiente contenido para desplazarse */
}

.content {
  height: 700px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.87, 0, 0.13, 1);
  /*     transform-style: preserve-3d; */
}

.sticky-element {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ff9900;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sticky-element">
      Elemento Sticky
    </div>
    <div class="content target">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <!-- Más contenido aquí -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se entiende bien cómo debiera funcionar,  y el ejemplo es extenso pero no aporta mucho al entendimiento.

Como sea, me da la impresión que piensas que la posición de un elemento no debiera variar con el scroll. Que si hay un contenedor de 700px el contenedor siguiente no tiene por qué tener un content rect top distinto de 700 sin importar el scroll.

Bueno, **resulta que no es así**. `element.getBoundingClientRect()` se mide respecto al elemento window (la pantalla visible) y no respecto de `document`. (que puede tener altura infinita)

Para saber la posición absoluta del contenedor debes sumar la propiedad top de tu *boundingClientRect* con el valor de `window.scrollY`.  Ahí podrás ver que **la suma de ambos es constante** mientras vas haciendo scroll por la página, hasta que se activa el comportamiento sticky y de ahí en adelante su top es fijo, mientras que window.scrollY sigue cambiando. Esa es la señal de que está pegado al tope del contenedor.

```js
var stickyElement = document.querySelector(".sticky-element");
var contentElement = document.querySelector(".content");
const fixed_bottom_debug = document.querySelector(".fixed_bottom_debug")

var lastStickyElementPosition = stickyElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var minScale = 0.5; // Valor mínimo de escala
var smoothness = 0.0005; // Suavidad de la transición

function computePositions() {
  const elementTop = stickyElement.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    absoluteElementTop = Math.round(elementTop + window.scrollY),
    delta = absoluteElementTop - lastStickyElementPosition,
    scrollTop = window.scrollY.toFixed(0),
    debugContent = "position " + absoluteElementTop + "  delta " + delta,
    scale = 1;
  return {
    scrollTop,
    elementTop,
    absoluteElementTop,
    delta,
    debugContent,
    scale
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

  let {
    scale,
    scrollTop,
    elementTop,
    absoluteElementTop,
    delta,
    debugContent
  } = computePositions()

  if (delta < 0) {
    // El elemento se está moviendo hacia abajo
    // Calcular la escala gradualmente con un valor mínimo
    scale = Math.max(minScale, 1 - (absoluteElementTop * smoothness));

    fixed_bottom_debug.innerHTML = ("<b>scroll up</b>." + debugContent + " scale " + scale);


  } else if (delta > 0) {
    // El elemento se está moviendo hacia arriba
    scale = Math.max(minScale, 1 - (absoluteElementTop * smoothness));
    fixed_bottom_debug.innerHTML = ("<b>scroll up</b>." + debugContent + " scale " + scale);

  } else {
    scale = 1;
    // El elemento no se está moviendo verticalmente
    fixed_bottom_debug.innerHTML = ("<b>no scroll</b> window.scrollTop." + scrollTop +
      ' + elementTop ' + elementTop + ' = ' + absoluteElementTop);
  }
  contentElement.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
  lastStickyElementPosition = absoluteElementTop;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  height: 1000vh;
  /* Asegúrate de que haya suficiente contenido para desplazarse */
}

.content {
  height: 700px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.87, 0, 0.13, 1);
  /*     transform-style: preserve-3d; */
}

.sticky-element {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ff9900;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.fixed_bottom_debug {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  position: fixed;
  height: 2em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sticky-element">
      Elemento Sticky
    </div>
    <div class="content target">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <!-- Más contenido aquí -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fixed_bottom_debug"></div>
```

El código que limpié tanto como pude,  *debiera* funcionar pero no puedo asegurarlo porque sigo sin entender qué necesitas que haga. De todos modos, si no te resulta con esto, prueba algún tutorial para hacerlo con un [InterSectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Yo lamentablemente tengo muy poca experiencia con esa API y sólo ha he ocupado para detectar colisiones.

Comment: Me has salvado, muchas gracias. La idea es hacer como una animación entre 3 divs, ya que las 3 tiene el position sticky solo me faltaba hacer que al pasar el scroll por la segunda la primera empezara a encogerse y el mismo proceso con la tercera y segunda, aqui encontré una pagina donde esta la animacion que trato de decir:
Se encuentra en la sexta sección de la pagina
[https://www.contiant.com/](https://www.contiant.com/)